# How to confirm Hard disk is perfect no problem?

Tags: hard-drive

How to confirm  any SATA/PATA Hard disk is perfect no problem? no bad sector on any other problem. I'm purchasing just 2 month used SATA HDD from a friend in less price.

How can i confirm hard disk will work perfectly, current condition is healthy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard drive manufacturers diagnostic tools: [hitachi](http://www.hitachigst.com/hdd/support/download.htm) / [samsung](http://www.samsung.com/global/business/hdd/support/utilities/ES_Tool.html) / [western digital](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=502&sid=30&lang=en) / [seagate (& maxtor)](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?locale=en-US&name=SeaTools&vgnextoid=720bd20cacdec010VgnVCM100000dd04090aRCRD) / [fujitsu](http://sdd.toshiba.com/main.aspx?Path=ServicesSupport/FujitsuDrivesUSandCanada/SoftwareUtilities) (now it's a toshiba brand but I don't have found a specific toshiba tool)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, I believe there is a built in utility to check for bad sectors under "My Computer".

I think this how-to explains the steps.

http://www.ehow.com/how_5094803_check-bad-sectors.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following alternatives. They're all *freeware*.

- [Active@ HD Monitor](http://www.disk-monitor.com/)
- [HDD Health](http://www.panterasoft.com/)
- [Disk Checkup](http://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm)
- [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/)
- [SeaTools](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/support/downloads/seatools)

Comment: I have *nothing* against FOSS, but sometimes you really *do* get what you pay for. SpinRite is tried-and-true, and has been refined over more than a decade, perhaps two.

SeaTools is a decent answer if the HDD is Seagate, but I'm not sure a SMART scan is as good as a level-4 or level-5 SpinRite scan.